# What am I supposed to do in this exercise?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So my teacher was very vague when introducing this concept and most of the class didn't get it. We're analyzing the continuity of functions from $\mathbb{R^2}$ into $\mathbb{R}$

The exercise asks to analyze the continuity of the following function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy+1}{y}x^2,\text{ for } y\neq 0$$
$$f(x,y) = 0 \text{ for } y=0$$

My interpretation is that the function isn't continuous, and I should be able to prove that the limit on this function does not exist along any points nearing the $y=0$  line. But I simply don't know how to do it

Another interpretation is that if I can prove there is at least one point $(x,0)$ such that the limit for $f(x,y)$ is different from $0$ near it, then I can say the function is not continuous, although this is a much weaker assertion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the path $\;y=mx^2\;,\;\;m\neq0\;$ a parameter, so that the limit you want is

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{mx^3+1}{mx^2}x^2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{mx^2+1}m=\frac1m$$

and thus the limit depends on $\;m\;$, so that the function's limit doesn't axist at the origin.

Comment: Ok but just proving dicontinuity at the origin is enough right? I don't have to prove it for all the y=0 line?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio That function is continuous in the whole plane without the origin, as each split definition is continuous everywhere...except at the origin, opf course.

Comment: And what happens all along the x-axis? That's what I'm failing to visualize

Comment: Along the $\;x\,-$ axis the function equals zero, a constant and thus continuous function.

Comment: Yes, but the limit along the x-axis does not exist. Try to take the limit of the function at (1,0) using a standard circle parametrization: $\alpha(x)=(cosx,sinx)$. Plug that into the function and it's divergent, thus the limit along the x axis does not exist, so the function must also be discontinuous in an infinite amount of places

Comment: (maybe even the whole x-axis but I don't know how to prove that)